# MySQL: как проверить связанность таблиц по id?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть 2 таблицы в MySQL. Первая с марками автомобилей имеет столбцы: `id` и  `title_mark`. Вторая с моделями марок имеет: `id`, `title_model` и `id_mark`. Числовые значения `id` в первой таблице должны соответствовать `id_mark` во второй.

Как проверить идентичность (наличие) этих идентификаторов? Например, может получиться, что `id` в первой таблице есть, а во второй `id_mark` не существует и наоборот.

Другими словами, нужно показать каких `id` из первой таблицы не существует в столбце `id_mark` из второй.

Comment: А у вас foreign key объявлен ? Он гарантирует, что в подчиненной таблице не может быть ID которых нет в главной, он просто не позволит создать такие записи или удалить марку, когда на нее есть ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить список автомобилей с несуществующей маркой можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  c.*
FROM
  cars AS c
LEFT JOIN
  marks AS m
ON
  c.id_mark = m.id
WHERE
  m.id IS NULL
```

Аналогичный запрос можно составить и для марок автомобилей

```
SELECT
  m.*
FROM
  marks AS m
LEFT JOIN
  cars AS c
ON
  c.id_mark = m.id
WHERE
  c.id_mark IS NULL
```